# How to align wires in an RJ-45, from photo

Tags: ethernet, cable

From my ISP, I have the installation of network in the below photo. However I would like to cut the cable and drag it back through the wall it is coming from, and put an RJ-45 plug on it.

[image: Wires]

However they are not lined up as I expected, like this:

[image: RJ-45_TIA-568A]

or this:

[image: RJ-45_TIA-568B]

My question is: **when i connect an RJ-45 to the cable - do I put them in the exact same order as they are already installed in my photo?** As you can see, I have no formal education regarding this matter.

Thanks for your time.

(image source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_connector#pinouts )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're planning to *cut* the cables out of those punch blocks and manually crimp RJ45 ends on to them, then yes, you can follow the diagrams you have. This would end up resulting in more or less a long Ethernet cable with two normal ends that has been run through the wall.

Punch-down blocks will often have different "pinouts" for the wires, so wires going into them may not have the same ordering as those in an RJ45 connector end. If you are planning to add new *jacks* to the ends of the cables once you've moved them, you will want to follow the wiring diagram printed on the jack itself. Most all jacks I've seen used for this purpose will have wiring diagrams printed on them.

I could be completely wrong, but far as I know, most all commercially sold Ethernet cables are wired as TIA-568B, so if you're crimping your own ends, I'd follow that standard. Same goes for if there's multiple wirings printed on a punch-down keystone jack. The real key is to keep the twisted pairs together and to make the pinouts on each end of the cable the same, but it never hurts to follow the standard.